# What are the 'quadrants' in TV testing?

Tags: terminology, audience-measurement

When talking of the upcoming S.H.I.E.L.D. TV series, ABC Entertainment Group President Paul Lee [said](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2013/05/14/abc-announces-2013-14-schedule-marvel-s-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-gets-tuesday-berth-once-upon-a-time-spin-off-to-thursdays.html):

> “We don’t normally talk about testing, but [Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.] tested so well in all four quadrants," Lee said.

What are the four quadrants he's referring to?  It sounds like they're splitting up demographics into four groups, and I'm looking to find out what that split is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to an article from [TV Guide](http://www.tvguide.com/celebrity-blogs/Four-quadrant-Television-19631.aspx), the four quadrants are split according to male or female and old or young.  From another [site](http://indiesunchained.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/his-and-hers-demos/) about audience demographics, it appears the the old-young split is made at age 25.

Edit:  Here's an image I found on a [site for independent filmmakers](http://www.indietalk.com/):

[image: four quadrants]